# Can you create calendar event for a future date at a specific time with Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I want to create a calendar event based on when emails come into my inbox. I would like for this to occur 14 days after the email arrives, but specifically at 9am in the morning. Right now I am trying to make the script run the next day at 9am, and then create an event 13 days from that run time. Is there any more effective way to do this in the script itself?

```
//This script runs the next day around 9am, calendar invite will be created for 13 days form then 
    to account for the next day
var now = new Date().getTime();
var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
for (i in threads) {
  cals[0].createEvent(reminderLabel + '- '+ i.getFirstMessageSubject(),
    new Date(now+(MILLIS_PER_DAY*13)),
      new Date(now+(MILLIS_PER_DAY*13)+900000), {description: i.getPermalink()});
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create directly on email arrival an event that will take place 14 days later, or do you want to create an event 14 days after the email arrives?

Comment: For example, if I got an email today at 12pm, I want the event to be in 14 days specifically at 9am. If another email came in at 3pm, I want it to make another event in 14 days at 9am. So I really just care about the date the email arrives, not necessarily the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I use to create events when I just want to notify myself 6 hours from now and I use a rather cryptic input technique which is described the html placeholder attribute of a textbox `EventTitle/hours/min/` I split the input string on `/` if the length is 3 or less then I automatically create 30,15,0 minute notification but I just created an event two weeks from today and had a notification that will occur tommorow using this input string `TwoWeeksFromToday/336/0/18720`.  Here's the code.

```
function createEventWithReminders(eA) {
  var minute=60*1000;
  var hour=60*minute;
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(getGlobal('DailyEventsId'));
  var now=new Date();
  var startValue=now.valueOf() + (Number(eA[1]) * hour ) + (Number(eA[2]) * minute);
  var start=new Date(startValue);
  var endValue=start.valueOf() + (10 * minute);  
  var end=new Date(endValue);
  var event=cal.createEvent(eA[0], start, end);
  if(eA.length>3) {
    for(var i=3;i<eA.length;i++) {
      event.addEmailReminder(eA[i]);
    }
  }
  else{
    event.addEmailReminder(0);
    event.addEmailReminder(15);
    event.addEmailReminder(30);
  }
  return true;
}
```

I've been using it this way for about 3 years.

Image of Calendar Event:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### You can run the function automatically daily on [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

The content of the function should be the following

- Implement an `if` statement to list only the messages that arrived in the last 24 hours
- Create a date object that has the time 9:00 am of today
- For all new messages, create an event in 13 days from 9:00 am today

Sample (bind an installable time-driven trigger to it):

```
function myFunction() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var cals = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var nineAm = new Date();
  nineAm.setHours(09);
  nineAm.setMinutes(00);
  nineAm = nineAm.getTime();
  var reminderLabel = "Reminder: ";
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  for (var i =0; i <threads.length; i++) {
    if(threads[i].getLastMessageDate().getTime()>=(now-24*3600*1000)){
      Logger.log(threads[i].getLastMessageDate());
      cals[0].createEvent(reminderLabel + '- '+ threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject(),
        new Date(nineAm+(MILLIS_PER_DAY*13)),
          new Date(nineAm+(MILLIS_PER_DAY*13)+900000), {description: threads[i].getPermalink()});
    }else{
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var event = CalendarApp.createEventFromDescription('Remind for email in 14 days at 9 am');
event.setTime(event.getEndTime(), event.getEndTime()); // fix Calendar bug with start date
```

Documentation: [`createEventFromDescription(description)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEventFromDescription(String)).